# How to filter data in R and plot word cloud?

Tags: r, filter, shiny, word-cloud

Hello I would like to plot a word cloud. The user can filter between different documents. After filtering the only filtered data should be displayed. How can I do that? My dataset looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

I have `selectInput()` where the client can select the document number. For the beginning I want that only selecting one is possible but for later maybe also multiple. This is my ui.R code snippet:

```
            box(
              title = "Document Control",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 4,
              selectInput("doc", label="Select Document", choices = Wcloud.Data$document, selected = 1)
            ),

            #
            box(
              title = "Frequency Control",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 4,
              height = 142,
              sliderInput("minFreq", label = "Minimum Frequency", min = 1, max = 50, value = 15)
            ),

            #
            box(
              title = "Number Control",
              status = "primary",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 4,
              height = 142,
              sliderInput("maxNum", label = "Maximum Number of Words", min = 1, max = 100, value = 30)
            ),

            box(
              title = "Graph", 
              status = "danger", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 12,
              plotOutput("plotWcloud")
            ),
```

And my server.R snippet:

output$plotWcloud <- renderPlot({

```
Wcloud.Data.filtered <- Wcloud.Data %>%

  filter(input$doc == document)

Wcloud.Data.filtered %>%

#set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = term, freq = count, min.freq = input$minFreq, max.words = input$maxNum, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

})

Answer (score 0):

you need build reactive functions in shiny, so the R knows that when `input$doc` changes it updates your document choice. I would personally calculate the filtered dataset in one `reactive({})` and then call this reactive filtered dataset within the `renderPlot({})` function.

```
filtered <- reactive({
Wcloud.Data.filtered <- Wcloud.Data %>%
  filter(document == input$doc)
}) 

renderPlot({
wordcloud(words = filtered()$term, freq = filtered()$count, 
min.freq = input$minFreq, max.words = input$maxNum, random.order=FALSE, 
rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))

})
```

Remember to use this logic for every user input widget and notice the brackets next to the reactive data frame `filtered`. Thats the way of calling the reactive dataset. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you very much. can you give me also the code for the wordcloud complete? this doesnt work for me:     `wordcloud(data = filtered(), words = term, freq = count, min.freq = input$minFreq,
              max.words = input$maxNum, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))`

Comment: also the wordcloud function does not has a data input. is their an alternative solution?

Comment: Sorry, I meant by the `data` argument your actual corpus - so instead of `words = term` it should be `words = filtered()`. 
I will update my answer. Hope this works!

Comment: but words has to bee update and also freq has to be updated? I will try your example. i mean i have to say behind the filtered() something with term otherwise words just refer to the function?

Comment: I edited again, now both arguments are being updated and specify the respective column in the filtered dataset.

Comment: now it works but kind not perfect. If I select for example document 1 and more than 30 words it plots me all the words, but no word has a count of 30. So If I play a little bit with my slider it is still not perfect. Maybe my filtering needs something more or what do you think?

Comment: Which input are you changing? `input$maxNum` is suppossed to regulate the number of words with the highest count. That means if you slide to 30 than you should get the 30 words with the highest count - not words which have a count of 30. If you change the `input$minFreq` the word cloud should only present words which have a minimal count of the number you have slided to.

Comment: yes thats correct. Iam speaking about the `input$minFreq`. If I put this on 30, it plots me all words. But the highets count is only 29. So if I go to 29 it only plots me 1 word which is correct. But why it plots all words if I go to 30? Something seems incorrect

Comment: That is really odd.. without seeing the code I cannot really think of a solution. Sorry!

Comment: I have exactly used your code. Put i think the problem is on the filter code. Because maybe it also calculates for example if I select document no 1, maybe also 10,11 because of the “1”. Or is the filter code correct?

Comment: I think the problem is with the min.freq and max.words code. Ach I don’t know bro :D but need to fix it

Comment: So normally, when you move the `input$minFreq` to 30 it shoul show no words if there is no word with a count of 30 right? It is definetely weird, that it works with all numbers under 30. And in my opinion all inputs are correct and there should be no problem with filtering.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what happens. But I dont know if inside the filter() function something is wrong

Comment: To debug you can temporarily build in a `tableOutput` widget in your ui.R and reference a table output of the filtered dataframe in the server.R. Then you can check if the feltereing is working because you can see the actual dataframe which will be fed after user input into the wordcloud.